# Golang linter issues 'context loading failed: no go files to analyze'

Tags: go, lint

We are using

- `golangci-lint` version `1.40.1` together with
- golang version `1.16.4`

in our project for linting our Golang code.

Until now, what we did is running this bash script (from the root
directory of our repository):

```bash
if ! [ -x "$(command -v golangci-lint)" ]; then
    echo "Fetching linter..."
    go install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint
    go mod tidy
fi

golangci-lint run --build-tags="unit contract container"
```

With some recent updates of Golang and `golangci-lint`, we suddenly face this error message:

```
ERRO Running error: context loading failed: no go files to analyze
```

There is a [lengthy post on GitHub regarding this issue](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/825) but the only useful suggestion there is to turn off the `GO111MODULE` env variable. When I run the linter with `GO111MODULE` turned off like

```bash
GO111MODULE=off golangci-lint run --build-tags="unit contract container"
```

the upper error message disappears but instead I am getting lots of false linting errors like:

```
api/router.go:152:5: undeclared name: `PermissionUpdatePackage` (typecheck)
                                PermissionUpdatePackage,
                                ^
```

My go environment looks like this:

```
GO111MODULE=on
GOPATH=/Users/USER/workspace/go
GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
GOPRIVATE=*.CUSTOMER.com
GOSS_PATH=/usr/local/bin/goss
```

I tried to install the linter via `go get...` as well as `go install ...` and finally `brew install golangci-lint` which seems to be the recommended way following [this documentation](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/install/#macos).

Comment: Have you tried `GO111MODULE=off golangci-lint run --build-tags="unit contract container"`, i.e. disabling modules for the execution of the command? (I didn't quite get where exactly you placed the `export GO111MODULE=off`. Also you mention "With some recent updates", what updates?

Comment: thanks, I will clarify my question. And yes, I tried running `GO111MODULE=off golangci-lint run --build-tags="unit contract container"`

Comment: Golang (even the v1.16 branch) got lots of security fixes after 1.16.4, and go has great backward compatibility. Why are you using that specific version?

Comment: Thank you for updating your question with the solution you found! Could you please reformat it as an answer to your own question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: when I resolved all the issues listed by `go mod tidy`, this error went away

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running a `go get ./...` in the root of the project eventually solved the issues. In between we ran the following commands that probably cleared some (module?) caches that might have caused trouble as well:

```bash
golangci-lint cache clean && go clean -modcache -cache -i
golangci-lint run -v --timeout=5s
```

The error message

```
ERRO Running error: context loading failed: failed to load packages: timed out to load packages: context deadline exceeded
```

in the latter command pointed us to [this GitHub post](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/395) that made me try out `go get ./...`

For installing the linter (with a specified version), we ended up with this script:

```bash
linter_version='1.40.1'
if ! [ -x "$(command -v golangci-lint)" ]; then
    echo "Fetching linter..."
    # we cannot install linter in the project directory, otherwise we get dependency errors
    # hence, temporarily jump into the /tmp directory
    pushd /tmp > /dev/null
    GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@v"${linter_version}" 2>&1
    popd >/dev/null
fi
```

Comment: `go get ./...` solved the problem for me.

Comment: `go mod tidy` also resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue,
for me solutions was to install linter with a shell script instead of snap `-,-